# How can fix this “Dropzone already attached” error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

**HTML**

```
<div class="dz dz-clickable dz-started">
   <div id="design-image" class="dropzone"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("div#design-image").dropzone({url:"myUrl"});
```

I set up `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` still not working.

Answer (score 23):

You have to put autoDiscover option before $(document).ready, like :

```
//Dropzone Configuration
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Manual dropzone init
  $("div#design-image").dropzone({url:"myUrl"});
});`
```

Comment: Seems like there was a change when I updated jQuery in my project where Dropzone is initiated before the autodiscover flag was set. Setting the autodiscover flag before ready function is called worked for me.

Comment: head banging with it from almost an hour now

Answer (score 4):

You already have a reference to the dropzone by giving your html element a class of "dropzone". No need to create it via jquery. Reference it using:

`var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("div#design-image");`

And your `$("div#design-image")` selector is in-efficient. Ids are supposed to be unique across your whole dom tree. Use `$("#design-image")`

Answer (score 2):

in your dropzone.js changes:

```
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
```

to:

```
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```